# Cant use fopen in expansion folder on some Android devices

Tags: android, file, expansion

Our game is bigger than 50Mb so we will be using an expansion file. This supposedly goes in the /Android/obb/package-name/ folder. To test it, we copy the file to that location using Windows file explorer.

To find the location, we call

String dir1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

However, on some device, it cant find the file

e.g. the GalaxyTab2.7.0 - the above call returns the location /storage/sdcard0, but it cant open the file /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/package-name/base.tcf, even though we have copied it there, using Windows file explorer, to the Android/obb/package-name/ folder.

Now, maybe this "Android" folder is not the same one as the storage/sdcard one - maybe I CAN only put it on an sdcard ? But this same thing works on Nexus 10 and Sony Experia device, with the same paths, which don't have sd cards in them.

To get this working on other devices we had to put READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in the manifest file. Maybe there is another permission ? Maybe once we actually download the expansion file, it will just work, but we can't test it otherwise.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Shaun Southern

Comment: Grrr. I put an sd card into the device with the file on. It ignored it. I wrote a file out. It appeared in the internal storage. But then I noticed my original folder in Internal storage had disappeared!? I wrote it back, and now it works. I can only imagine the file system reporting through windows and android were out of sync and the file actually wasn't visible to android.

Comment: Now, I still cant get the Kindle Fire to read the file. And I don't think it has an SD card slot. Also, I write a file out (using native code and fwrite) and it appears to work - but I cant find it. Maybe more problems with differences between android file system and windows...?

Comment: not of course that it matters in the end, as the Amazon "shop" doesn't have the need for expansion files, so I can build everything into the apk file, but it makes the process more unwieldy for testing. One of those days :)